# compare columns in the same file

Tags: awk

My file has thousands of lines an it looks like

```
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   0.0  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4496                12011G1                   473856.2 1960800.9   0.0  1000001
R4496                12011G1                   473856.2 1960800.9  64.0  1000001
```

what i want to get as output is

```
R4604                17131G1                   499456.1 1966201.0   8.5  1000001
R4496                12011G1                   473856.2 1960800.9  64.0  1000001
```

So if columns 1-5 are identical just get one line and if columns 1-4 are identical and have different values in column 5 remove the line with column 5 value 0.0

thanks for your help
Alejandro

Comment: Your specification is incomplete. When columns 1-4 are identical can there be other values besides 0 and a single non-zero value? Is the file sorted by the combination of the 5 columns? Are there ever lines with column 5 equal to zero and no other value?

Comment: Also, is column 6 always the same (though I don't suppose it really matters)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a sorted value and that column 5 is always either 0 or the same non-zero value for each line in a group and that there are no lines to be kept with column 5 equal to 5:

```
awk '$5 != 0 {key = $1 $2 $3 $4 $5; if (prev != key) {print saved}; prev = key; saved = $0} END {print saved}' inputfile
```